# How to restrict a user ID to have only one Login at a time in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

The Thing i want to do is , We have a user who is logged in a device .We have to restrict that user to login from other device.

To Login into Other device he should have to log out from the first device.

I have tried to create authentication token via web API.
Every time a user login ,a new oath token is generally passed in the request headers. (Token would be expire on logout.)
If Same User try to login from other device a new Oath token would be generated 
is there anyway to check if a token is already assigned to that user then do not allow him to login

What if, 
1.user close the working tab or browser
2.or He navigate to other web page by changing the URL

Are there other solutions to ensure one concurrent login per user ?

Answer (score -1):

This should be simple enough to make sure a user have only one login at a time.

**Steps to do would be (ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC):**

Step 1: As soon as user login, check if session for this user already exists.

Step 2: If Session already exists, delete the on going session (Here you can also prompt a message to user if he wants to stop currently going session and start a new one.)

Step 3: On User's action you may delete current session and start a new session for the user.

Step 4: If there is no current session going on, you can simply create a new one .

**Update:**

**For ASP.NET WEB API**

Here you have to use Authentication token.

On login you can provide authentication token to user.

On Relogin you can check if token is already issued for this user, and accordingly perform your action.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have queries.

I assume you know how to code above, if not let me know.

Comment: As there any way to add a session in ASP.NET WEB API. Could we maintain Sessions in Restful API's

Comment: Og I see.. No you cant create Sessions in Restful APIs.  I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DheerajKumar can you please explain how we can check that token is already issued to the user? How I can invalidate previously issued tokens?